# How can I change the language metadata with ffmpeg without converting video?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, quicktime

I want just to change in a MOV video the language from English to Spanish.
I'm using

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -metadata:s:1:1 language=spa out.mov
```

I add `out.mov` because is mandatory, but I don't want to create a new file, just change metadata.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

FFmpeg won't change metadata in place. It will have to create a new file, but you can avoid conversion by specifying copy mode

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:a:1 language=spa out.mov
```